# How to wake up the device and turn on screen on notification?

Tags: android

I have an app that needs to wake up the screen when it creates a notification. I used to do it like this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((
PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | 
PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | 
PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

but this is deprecated, and this no longer works on Android 4 (whether it's the new support library or something else I'm not sure) so now I can't update my app because it won't have functionality users depend on.

Is there a way to do this, or is Google saying this functionality shouldn't exist (except for their apps)?